# An error happened during template parsing(springboot+thymeleaf)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

> I provide all the things but i donot know why I am getting this type
> of issue
> And use right thymeleaf syntax but it through a null exception
>
> I got below type of error

```
Wed Sep 08 21:03:20 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/page.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/page.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
```

> page.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="/fragments/head"></head>
<body>
<nav th:replace="/fragments/nav :: nav-front"></nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div col="7" th:utext="${page.content}"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div th:replace="/fragments/footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> PagesController.kt

```
package com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.controller

import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Page
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.repository.PageRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.ui.Model
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class PagesController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var pageRepository: PageRepository

    @GetMapping
    fun home(model: Model?):String?{
        val page: Page?= pageRepository.findBySlug("home")
        if (model != null) {
            model.addAttribute("page",page)
        }
        return "page"
    }
}
```

> pageRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.repository

import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Page
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

interface PageRepository : JpaRepository<Page,Int> {
    fun findBySlug(slug: String?): Page?
    fun findBySlugAndIdNot(slug: String?, id: Int?): Page?
    fun findAllByOrderBySortingAsc(): List<Page?>?
}
```

> page.kt

```
package com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model

import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.Size

@Entity
@Table(name = "pages")
data class Page(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id:Int=0,
    @Size(min=2,message = "Title must be four character")
    val title:String="",
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var slug:String="",
    @Size(min=4,message = "Content must contain four character")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    val content:String="",
    var sorting:Int=0
)
```

> I got this type of response when i call localhost:8080 in my browser

```
Wed Sep 08 21:03:20 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/page.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/page.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "page.content" (template: "page" - line 9, col 22)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "page.content" (template: "page" - line 9, col 22)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardUtextTagProcessor.doProcess(StandardUtextTagProcessor.java:87)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'content' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:337)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
    ... 69 more
```

Comment: Generally, in the Entity, we use in the tag @Column the table field's name for with one. I saw that you don't do it. Maybe it's cause this error. Look the "cause by" in the stack trace. It show the field content cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the stack trace shows:

```
Property or field 'content' cannot be found on null
```

Which means you are trying to call `content` on something, but that something is `null`.

The only line in your Thymeleaf template that seems to match this is:

```
<div col="7" th:utext="${page.content}"></div>
```

So it means the `page` model attribute is `null`.

The controller puts stuff in the model, so we need to look there why this is null:

```
        val page: Page?= pageRepository.findBySlug("home")
        if (model != null) {
            model.addAttribute("page",page)
        }
```

My guess is that `page` is `null` here because there is nothing for slug `home` in your database?

Comment: what is the reason for getting page as  null. I check it and found page contain null value so the error occurs. what is the reason for page null

Comment: `page` would be `null` if there is nothing in your database that has a slug `home`.